# Laravel access denied for user myproject@localhost

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, migration

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and I'm usinh ssh to log into server.
I'm trying to make  anew migration and I ran:

`php artisan make:migration create_logs_table --create=logs`

but i'm getting this error:

`{"error":{"type":"PDOException","message":"SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myproject'@'localhost' (using password: YES)","file":"\/home\/public_html\/myproject\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Connectors\/Connector.php","line":47}}`

I haven't changed my env file - database, username and password are still the same. When I use command line and try to create a new migration, I got this error.
Why I get this error for user `myproject` -> my username is another - this is the name of the project.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your .env file? The error definitely states that Laravel cannot acces the DB because of wrong credentials.

Comment: There's nothing special going on here. Your MySQL credentials are incorrect.

Comment: I haven't changed env file, it's fine - site is working and no problem with database. When I run this migration through command line, I get this error. And the error is: "Access denied for user myproject@localhost -> why name of the project is set as user? :)

Comment: The artisan command use the credentials provided in the .env file. Can't you post the .env file? The artisan command does not use different creds than the website.

Comment: As far as I know in 4.2 there is no .env file but the database configuration is read from app/config/database.php. Try a php artisan env just to be sure that you are in the right environment config file. If the credentials are good it must work.

Comment: There is env file, I've made it. When I run -> php artisan env, it shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Well CLI in Laravel 4 can be tricky. Despite of .env file you could also have different enviroment in web and in CLI set.

So... first of all if you have for example local enviroment - in the `.env` file:

`export APP_ENV=local`

but this is not enough. You have to open your `bootstrap/start.php` file and set your machine to specify enviroment:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() use ($app){
    $env = array_get($_SERVER, 'APP_ENV');
    if(empty($env)){
        $envs = [
            'local' => ['your_machine_name'],
        ];
        $env = $app->detectEnvironment($envs);
    }
    return $env;
});
```

Be sure that you have this all set and you're working on good enviroment.